# MPAndroidChart and View Binding for Custom Marker

Tags: android, view, binding, mpandroidchart, marker

Since find *android.synthetic* is deprecated I am trying to convert my fragment that uses MPAndroidChart to use View Binding. I have been successful at converting the Chart, but cannot figure out how to convert the Custom Marker to use View Binding.

The linear trend chart definition:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mywx.TrendCharts"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/trendChart">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/trendChart2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the Custom Marker resource definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    android:id="@+id/markerPop">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chartTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/selTime"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkAccent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:background="@color/DarkPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chartValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/null_fraction"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkAccent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chartTime"
        android:background="@color/DarkPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Relevant code for the trend chart (the view is returned from onCreateView):

`return TrendChartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).trendChart`

And in the onViewCreated:

`chart = view.findViewById(R.id.trendChart2) as LineChart // Define the LineChart object`

So this part works. However to define a Custom Marker for this chart you need a call like this:

`CustomMarker(it,R.layout.marker_pop)`

So, you need to pass the layout resource in order to define the Custom Marker:

`chart.marker = CustomMarker(it,R.layout.marker_pop)`

But how can this be converted to using View Binding, since the view is initiated like this:

`markerView = MarkerPopBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) // Initialize Pop Up view`

I'm showing my basic understanding of Android and Kotlin ... so some help much appreciated! Perhaps not possible without an update to CustomMarker? Or can markerView be pointed/cast/used by the results of creating a *CustomMarker*.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to convert? The `chart.marker =` line? If so, how did you do that using synthetics before and what exactly is wrong with what you have? View binding is just a convenience layer to avoid lots of `findViewById` calls, so if it's not convenient or relevant you don't have to use it everywhere. Would be helpful to include some more complete code samples

Comment: Trying to replace:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.marker_pop.view.*`

With:

`import com.unified.mywx.dataBinding.MarkerPopBinding`

And:

`val markerPop = activity?.let { CustomMarker(it, R.layout.marker_pop)}` 

`chart.marker = markerPop`
  with: `markerView = MarkerPopBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` and something like:  `markerPop = context?.let { CustomMarker(it,R.layout.marker_pop) }` which doesn't work. Looks like the `markerView` view isn't used. Cannot figure out how to use it in this context.

Comment: I don't see where you even needed the synthetic in the former use. Synthetics and view binding aren't usually relevant when you are creating the view programmatically. Does the former use work, with the synthetic import removed, and if not what is the error? Please add to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: No it doesn't work without using Synthetics. No way to reference `chartTime` and `chartValue`. 
Basically trying to figure out how to define `markerView` as a `CustomMarker` and set it as the `IMarker` for `chart`. Seems to be all about setting the `view` for the marker resource.

Comment: Is `CustomMarker` a class you have defined to extend `MarkerView`? If something else is inflating the view you won't be able to use view binding unless you can modify the part of the code inflating the view. However, you can still access child views in general with `TextView chartTime = markerPop.findViewById(R.id.chart_time)`

Comment: You might be able to use `binding = MarkerPopBinding.bind(markerPop)` instead of `inflate` too, then you can call `binding.chartTime` - depends what CustomMarker is doing internally.

Comment: Thanks Tyler V ... got me pointed in the right direction. Now working! See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To define a custom marker for the MPAndroidChart using View Binding do the following:

`import com.databinding.MarkerPopBinding`

Then in the onViewCreated, the code should look something like this:

```
markerPop = context?.let { CustomMarker(it,R.layout.marker_pop) } 
markerBind = markerPop?.let { MarkerPopBinding.bind(it) }
chart.marker = markerPop
```

The key is to define a binding between `markerPop` and `MarkerPopBinding`.

The code to display the data in a popup was changed from:

`markerView.chartTime.text =  String.format(context.getString(R.string.selTime), hour, minutes)`

To this, using the `markerBind` object.

`markerBind?.chartTime?.text =  String.format(context.getString(R.string.selTime), hour, minutes)`

A question lingers ... are there two views defined: `markerView` and `markerPop`!? Yes, I really do not know what is going on in detail, but it works!

Comment: I don't think you need the `markerView = MarkerPopBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) ` line in there - no need to inflate it if you then bind it to a pre-inflated view.

Comment: Yes, it is needed ... you get a "not initialized" error otherwise, so I think that there is only one view used/created `makerView` linked/syched/binded with `markerPop` ... but I'm way beyond my level of expertise!

Comment: I guarantee you do not need it, and if you have something referring to it that is throwing that error you should remove it and use `markerBind` there instead - otherwise you are inflating the view twice but only one of them is valid. When you delete it, you should also delete the class instance defining it so you can't use it anywhere.

Comment: Yes Tyler V, you were right. I had `markerView` reference elsewhere, which I deleted. So the link of `markerPop` to `MarkerPopBinding` is all that is needed. TY!